# Screen Pop Lightning experience new modal default values

Tags: lightning-experience

I want to use screenPop method from open CTI to create new object. I'm using code as below.

```
 sforce.opencti.screenPop({
        type: sforce.opencti.SCREENPOP_TYPE.NEW_RECORD_MODAL, //Review the arguments section.
        params:  { entityName: 'Lead' },
        callback: function(args) {
            console.log(args);
        } 
    } );
```

but I want to prepopulate some fields like phone. Does anyone know what should I put in params or that is not possible at all... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider the following code for Lightning Experience in Open CTI.

```
var lname ='Testname';
var phno = '123456789';
sforce.opencti.screenPop({
                          type: sforce.opencti.SCREENPOP_TYPE.NEW_RECORD_MODAL,
                                        params: {
                                            entityName: 'Contact',
                                            defaultFieldValues:{LastName:lname,Phone:phno}
                                        }

                                    });
```

It shows a popup window to create a new Contact record with given default values. (For Lightning Experience)

Ajay Krishna R

Comment: I think that at that time it was some issue with framework as it had started working after some time...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For the debugged code, seems that is not possible...